# How do you reconcile the DRY Principle with database efficiency?

Tags: database, performance, dry

*I will use Python in my code snippet and am referencing Django documentation, but this question is intended to be language agnostic*

From the Django tutorial:

> A model is the single, definitive source of data about your data. It contains the essential fields and behaviors of the data you’re storing. Django follows the DRY Principle. The goal is to define your data model in one place and automatically derive things from it.

It goes on to say

> It should execute SQL statements as few times as possible, and it should optimize statements internally.

How do we reconcile these two design philosophies? To explore the situation, let us assume that we have a table representing profiles. We also have a function `get_profile(profile_id)` in our data model which does the following:

- retrieves the row from the database
- performs some computation to generate additional properties
- returns this processed record as the Canonical Profile Representation

Next, we find we also need a `get_profiles(list_of_profile_ids)` function. The DRY principle, as I understand it, would mandate implementation along the lines of

```
function get_profiles(list_of_profile_ids):
    profiles = []
    for profile_id in list_of_profile_ids:
        profiles.append(get_profile(profile_id))
    return profiles
```

If our list of `profile_id`s is long, we are now performing many individual database queries. Is this not horribly inefficient, as compared to a function which performs a single database query for `profile_id in (id1, id2, id3)` and then performing the same computations on each row?

How does one reconcile DRY with keeping execution efficient?

Comment: Everything is efficient (runes fast enough) until you have data proving otherwise. Coding principles exist to make the programmers life better by simplifying the code and making it easier to reason about. Yes, sometimes (in fact, hopefully often and by default) we err on the side of simpler code instead of faster code. If nobody complains about the slowness, it's fast enough. That said, in this particular case you can just invert the relationship: provide an efficient implement of `get_profiles` (one database query)  and make `get_profile` call into it with a single-element list.

Comment: That is... a really good point. Thank you.

Comment: By the way, this question is too general for StackOverflow (not enough real code, not a real problem; too hypothetical). It should probably be on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/.